# How to set the image of one UIImageView to the image of Another UIImageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

Is there a very simple way to do this. This doesnt work, i know, but i was hoping for something along these lines:

```
_wantedCharacter.image = [UIImage _character0.image];
```

any suggestions? I just really dont want to go through and put the actual name of the image because I would have to do it a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if you think I'm rude, but looking at your example code, it looks like you lack the very basics of Objective-C (and maybe OOP)... It's surely nice to try to code immediately, but I think you should start by reading at least the basic doc on the language itself first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `_wantedCharacter` and `_character0` are of type `UIImageView`,

```
_wantedCharacter.image = _character0.image;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already loaded the image and added it to one your UIImageView instances, there is no point in loading it into another UIImage again. So, simply  do:

```
_wantedCharacter.image = _character0.image;
```